# Get current script's name and path

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the full path to a VBS script.
All the answers I have seen get the current cd excluding the path to the script. I want to get the path to the script.

For example: `%userprofile%\Desktop\script.vbs`

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58563983/edit) and post the code that you have tried !

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

`WScript.ScriptFullName` (full path)

or

`WScript.ScriptName` (just file name)